# can individuals resampled in reoccurring cross section surveys be considered as panel dataset?

Tags: sampling, survey, panel-data, cross-section

I have data from a reoccurring cross sectional firm survey, For every year a new sample was selected ( with replacement between years). The data is identified, so I can see the subset of firms appear in the sample of more than one year.

Can I treat this subset of reoccurring firms as an unbiased panel?

I would appreciate any pointers to relevant literature on this, as I was not able to find it.

I'm aware this 'panel' subsample  tends to be small,  but for some variables and confidence levels it may be enough.

Assuming 2 periods, no stratification and sampling proportional to size with each period, how should I construct sampling weights for it?
Would it be just the products of selection probabilities in each period (Pt1 * Pt2)?

My actual case is more complicated. I have samples from 9 years. Within each year firms are stratified by region and size ( small, medium, large), so firms will reappear more in  proportionally smaller strata.

Comment: For the firms that appear in multiple years, it sounds like repeated measures design with longitudinal data.  You would not want to treat these firms as an unbiased panel - a firm's responses will be correlated across years.

Comment: Are you planning an analysis based on model-based standard errors or on sampling standard errors?

Comment: @wcampbell: agreed on the serial correlations within firms over time. However, that happens to any panel data and can be solved by clustering s.d. by firm. It is not specific to this "panel within repeated cross-sections".

Comment: @SteveSamuels: good question. I guess both: First I'm trying to do some descriptive statistics (thus sampling s.e.), trying to separate intensive and extensive magins of the grow we see in a variable over time on the repeated cross sections data. Second, I'll do some model fixed effects estimates (thus model-based s.e.). Still sampling weights may be necessary to use Weighted Least Squares, discussed in [Solon, Haider and Wooldridg - 2013](http://www.nber.org/papers/w18859.pdf)

Comment: what survey is this?

Comment: @AnthonyDamico: mostly TIC-Empresa, which surveys how firms use  Information and Communication Technologies. There are also repeated cross-sections for some strata of IBGE firm surveys (PIA, PAC, PAC, PINTEC). These identified data RE not public. They are only accessible, with IBGEs permission, at their secure off-line 'dark data room', with firm ids criptographed, etc